# Can I get a CSV header but no row count in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, csv, formatting

When I do `psql --no-align --field-separator ','`, I get CSV output with a header containing field names and a trailer telling me how many rows were found.  To pass that into an analysis program, I need the header but not the trailer.  I can surely write a filter to pass the first N-1 lines of the psql output but I'd prefer to suppress the trailer.  Is there an option I'm missing that will turn on the header with `--tuples-only` or turn off the trailer?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`psql --no-align --field-separator ',' --pset footer` will turn off the row summary footer

Answer (score 2):

I found

```
COPY (...query...) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER;
```

at http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/dlarochelle/2011/12/11/outputing-to-csv-in-postgresql/.

It doesn't seem to work without the `TO STDOUT` but I can work with that.

Comment: You can also redirect the output to a file by replacing STDOUT with an absolute filepath like: '/tmp/out.csv'

Comment: Also see \copy for a wrapper in psql around COPY.  However, if using psql on the same system as the server, I prefer jcern's approach above.